# dynamically create a JavaScript object client side

Tags: javascript, json, object, dynamic

I need to create the JavaScript object below dynamically, but it's too complex.

```
var data = {
    "nodes":[
        {"id":"n1", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node1"}},
        {"id":"n2", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node2"}},
        {"id":"n3", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node3"}}
    ],
     "links":[
        {"id":"l1","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
        {"id":"l2","from":"n2", "to":"n3", "style":{"fillColor":"green", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
        {"id":"l3","from":"n3", "to":"n1", "style":{"fillColor":"blue", "toDecoration":"arrow"}}
    ]
};
```

and its a dynamic thing because I need to change the value of the id dynamically and sometimes I need to add more nodes and more links like below

```
var data = {
    "nodes":[
        {"id":"n1", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node1"}},
        {"id":"n2", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node2"}},
        {"id":"n3", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node3"}},
        {"id":"n3", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node3"}},
    ],
     "links":[
        {"id":"l1","from":"n1", "to":"n2", "style":{"fillColor":"red", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
        {"id":"l2","from":"n2", "to":"n3", "style":{"fillColor":"green", "toDecoration":"arrow"}},
        {"id":"l3","from":"n3", "to":"n1", "style":{"fillColor":"blue", "toDecoration":"arrow"}}
        {"id":"l3","from":"n3", "to":"n1", "style":{"fillColor":"blue", "toDecoration":"arrow"}}
        {"id":"l3","from":"n3", "to":"n1", "style":{"fillColor":"blue", "toDecoration":"arrow"}}
    ]
};
```

I want to create it using JavaScript

```
var data = {};
and data.nodes = ?;
and data.links = ?;
```

Not like add a specific

my question is how can I create

```
{"id":"n1", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node1"}},
```

using JavaScript and I want change the value of `id` and `loaded` and put it into that nodes information also, each time I have different number of nodes and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function :

```
function makeNode(n, loaded) {
    return {
        id: 'n' + n, 
        loaded: loaded || false, 
        style: { label: 'Node' + n }
    };
}
```

```js
data.nodes.push(makeNode(1));
data.nodes.push(makeNode(2, false));
data.nodes.push(makeNode(3, true));
```

```js
// data.nodes
[
    { id: 'n1', loaded: false, style: { label: 'Node1' } },
    { id: 'n2', loaded: false, style: { label: 'Node2' } },
    { id: 'n3', loaded: true,  style: { label: 'Node3' } }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add to an array:

```
var x = {"id":"n3", "loaded":true, "style":{"label":"Node3"}}; //the thing you want to add
data.nodes.push(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.instead of add information.I need to change the id and loaded dynamic...